# Converting for loop generated tabular data into Data frame

Tags: python

I have data (example A, B, C,D) imported from different excel files and I want to form a Data Frame by joining similar column from each excel file sheet. Each file sheets have more than 100 columns. I used pd.concat in for loops to easier data joining as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

A = pd.DataFrame({'q1': ['16', '5','16', '5','13', '3'], 
               'q2': ['16', '3','16', '10','6', '1'],'q3': ['1', '2','1', '5','12', '13'],'q4': ['30', '25','50', '9','7', '6'],\
                 'q5': ['15', '4','18', '8','3', '1'],'q6': ['11', '9','16', '5','13', '3'],'q7': ['20', '5','12', '5','3', '2']})

B = pd.DataFrame({'q1': ['1', '3','12', '5','1', '3'], 
               'q2': ['6', '13','6', '1','7', '3'],'q3': ['3', '4','1', '2','3', '1'],'q4': ['27', '22','5', '19','9', '1'],\
                 'q5': ['15', '4','18', '8','3', '1'],'q6': ['11', '9','16', '5','13', '3'],'q7': ['20', '5','12', '5','3', '2']})

C = pd.DataFrame({'q1': ['16', '5','16', '5','13', '3'], 
               'q2': ['16', '3','16', '10','6', '1'],'q3': ['1', '2','1', '5','12', '13'],'q4': ['30', '25','50', '9','7', '6'],\
                 'q5': ['15', '4','18', '8','3', '1'],'q6': ['11', '9','16', '5','13', '3'],'q7': ['20', '5','12', '5','3', '2']})

D = pd.DataFrame({'q1': ['16', '5','16', '5','13', '3'], 
               'q2': ['16', '3','16', '10','6', '1'],'q3': ['1', '2','1', '5','12', '13'],'q4': ['30', '25','50', '9','7', '6'],\
                 'q5': ['15', '4','18', '8','3', '1'],'q6': ['11', '9','16', '5','13', '3'],'q7': ['20', '5','12', '5','3', '2']})

#Iterating selection by for loop 
i=0
df_data = []
Dt= {}
for column in A: 
    # Select column contents by column 
    Aa =A[column] 
    Ba=B[column] 
    Ca=C[column]
    Da=D[column]
    Dk=pd.concat([Aa, Ba,Ca,Da],axis=1, keys=['T1', 'T2','T3', 'T4'])
    Dt[i]=pd.concat([Aa, Ba,Ca,Da],axis=1, keys=['T1', 'T2','T3', 'T4'])
    df_data.append(Dk)
df_data
```

For analysis purposes i want to extract each for loop iteration data as

```
qu1=df_data[0:1]
qu1
```

How, can i convent the data(qu1) into data-frame.I tried indexing qu1 in diferent ways  and i get error 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'

```
#qu1.to_excel(r'D:\desktop\Python_data\temp_dfs.xlsx', index = False)
#qu1.values
#qu1['col1'] = qu1['col1'].apply(np.array)
qu1.columns
```

I want to get individual data frame like these from df_data (generated by for loop above)

```
#Manual column selection into data frame with pd.contact 
data1=pd.concat([A['q1'], B['q1'],C['q1'],D['q1']],axis=1,keys=['T1','T2','T3', 'T4'])
data2=pd.concat([A['q2'],B['q2'],C['q2'],D['q2']],axis=1, keys=['T1', 'T2','T3', 'T4'])
data3=pd.concat([A['q3'], B['q3'],C['q3'],D['q3']],axis=1, keys=['T1','T2','T3', 'T4']) 
data4=pd.concat([A['q4'],B['q4'],C['q4'],D['q4']],axis=1, keys=['T1','T2','T3', 'T4'])
data5=pd.concat([A['q5'], B['q5'],C['q5'],D['q5']],axis=1, keys=['T1','T2','T3', 'T4']) 
data6=pd.concat([A['q6'], B['q6'],C['q6'],D['q6']],axis=1, keys=['T1', 'T2','T3', 'T4'])
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
```

Kindly, I am requesting help

Comment: Its not clear to me whether your problem is that Dt[0], for example, is not what you would expect (data1 in your desired output), or is it that you want named variables for each element of the list Dt? Because your code looks fine.

Comment: Dear BVJ thank you for kind response,  the for loop result i get is df_data which is correct except that i want to transform each iteration into data frame i.e.  qu1=df_data[0:1], qu2=df_data[1:2], qu3=df_data[2:3], qu4=df_data[3:4], qu5=df_data[4:5] qu6=df_data[5:6] and qu7=df_data[6:7]. I want qu1...to qu7 results to be like  data1.... to data6 results. Note that currently qu1...to qu7 results have ([...],) brackets, and i can not index i.e. if write qu1.values or qu1.columns it returns error 'list object have no...'. I need help how can i transform qu1...to qu7 into Data frame?

Comment: thanks for the clarification. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the comment, I think the only issue is that you'r not taking an element of a list, but a slice. So you should replace:

```
qu1 = df_data[0:1]
```

with

```
qu1 = df_data[0]
```

The reason is that in Python, if x is a list, then x[0] is the first element, while x[0:1] is the first slice of the list, which is still a list. Here a simple example:

```
[ins] In [1]: l = ['a', 'b', 'c']

[ins] In [2]: l[0]
Out[2]: 'a'

[ins] In [3]: l[0:1]
Out[3]: ['a']
```

Also, if you want to make your unpacking of the list simpler, you can write

```
qu1, qu2, qu3, qu4, qu5, qu6, qu7 = df_data
```

if df_data is a list of 7 elements, Python will assign each element in order to each of the variables on the left.

Comment: qu1 = df_data[0] worked perfectly the way i wanted Thank you very much @ BVJ. However with qu1 = df_data[0:1] also it worked i tricked the array into numpy array, see my posted answer

Comment: @Fulgence, if this solution worked please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer would help you, but I am assuming that you want to concatenate the data frames of A, B, C, and D into one, passing `T#` as a key. If this is the case, so you might do something like the following - You can read the documentation for more info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```py
# 1. combine all the given data frame into a list data structure

# 2. Use the concat method to sum them up and passing the Ts as a list to the keys argument.
df_cont = pd.concat([A, B, C, D], keys=['T1','T2','T3', 'T4'])
```

The resulted data frame would look like the following.

[image]

Comment: Dear salma thanks for kind contribution. However, my aim is not to concatenate data frame A,B,C, D  into one but concatenate each qi (i=1, 2, 3,...7) column from A,B,C,D into one data frame, kindly check my comment above to @BVJ. I want to  transform qu1, qu2....qu7 into data frame

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this as an additional answer to my own question. @ BVJ answer worked well but it also   worked by passing qu1[0:1] list into numpy array and then concatenate into data frame

```
qu1=df_data[0:1]
qu1 = np.array(qu1, dtype=np.float)
qu1=pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(qu1),columns = ['T1', 'T2','T3', 'T4'])
qu1
```